# What is high-resolution performance counter?

Tags: winapi, hardware

In the Win32 API there is a function QueryPerformanceCounter that queries the value of a very high-resolution performance timer.

What is "high-resolution performance timer"? Is it supported by hardware? What systems does not support it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Windows 7 on present generation processors, this is a reliable high precision (nanosecond) timer inside the CPU (HPET).

Under previous versions and on previous generations of processors, it is "something", which can mean pretty much *anything*. Most commonly, it is the value returned by the RDTSC instruction (or an equivalent, on non-x86), which may or may not be reliable and clock-independent. Note that RDTSC (originally, by definition, but not any more now) does not measure *time*, it measures *cycles*.

On current-and-previous-generation CPUs, RDTSC is usually reliable and clock-independent (i.e. it is now *really* measuring time), on *pre*-previous generation, especially on mobile or some multi-cpu rigs it is not. The "timer" may accelerate and decelerate, and even be different on different CPUs, causing "time travel".

**Edit:** The `constant tsc` flag in cpuid(0x80000007) can be used to tell whether RDTSC is reliable or not (though this does not really solve the problem, because what to do if it isn't, if there is no alternative...).

On yet older systems (like, 8-10 years old), some other timers may be used for QueryPerformanceCounter. Those may neither have high resolution at all, nor be terribly accurate.

Comment: Re: "Note that RDTSC does not measure time, it measures cycles.", it is important to note that you can calculate time in seconds directly as `freq * ticks`.

Comment: @Polynomial: No, you can't, because freq != const. On pretty much _every_ system today (and most systems during the last half-decade) frequency is being scaled dynamically to save power.

Comment: Interesting. What's the alternative?

Comment: If 1ms resolution is enough, `timeGetTime` is as good as you can get from a user process. If you're writing a driver, you can call `KeQueryInterruptTime`. If you need higher resolution, _good_ alternatives are sparse. If the system your program runs on has either a constant tsc or HPET, all is good. Otherwise you are without luck. QPC _may_ work reliably, or it may not.

Answer (score 1):

High resolution performance counters are usually pulled from the `rdtsc` instruction, which is an x86-specific way to fetch the number of CPU ticks that have occured since boot. The value of it is very precise, usually down to 100ns accuracy.

Compare this to `GetTickCount()`, which has an accuracy of roughly ~16ms.

On other architectures (which are out of the scope of Win32 APIs, since they only run on x86-based instruction sets) there may be different ways of doing this. For example, on ARM you can use the System Control Coprocessor (CP15) to do something similar.

Comment: @AlexK. - Yeah, it's ultimately up to the HAL. On x86, though, I don't see a reason to use something other than rdtsc because it's so precise. If I remember correctly, it uses the same source clock that is used to run interrupts, which are ludicrously accuratly timed.

Comment: @Polynomial: See my answer for a good reason why RDTSC should not be used, unless you are guaranteed that your customers don't use a CPU that is maybe 4 or 5 years old. RDTSC is only precise and accurate on _some_ CPUs, not necessarily all (and you can't really control what CPU your program runs on).

Comment: @Polynomial: No you can't, really. Although it is _precise_ because it a resolution on the order of nanoseconds, it is not _accurate_. And it does not correlate to time at all, unless it's a newer-generation CPU. Precision without accuracy means nothing. If I give you a number with 5000 digits of which 4990 digits are bogus, then the digit is none better than if I only gave you 10 digits in the first place (in fact, actually it's worse...).

Comment: @Damon - Very interesting. Seems like a real pain in the ass to deal with!